# Occurrences and order of substrings in a string using Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string that contains a lot of stuff, and I want to parse it and get the occurrences of the strings "sat" and "unsat" in the correct order.

Basically, the input is a string (see below), and the output would be
a List<Integer> where if I find "sat" I will put 1 and if "unsat" 0.

```
sat
(= abst1ring1 true)
(= availablering3 false)
(= intermring4 false)
(= availablering5 false)
(= availablering2 false)


unsat

sat
(= intermring5 false)
(= intermring2 false)
(= abstring5 true)
(= abstring2 true)
(= available1ring1 false)
(= interm1ring1 false)
(= abstring3 true)
(= availablering4 false)
(= abstring4 true)
(= intermring3 false)
(= htokenring2 3)
(= htokenring5 3)
(= htoken4 3)
(= htrigger1ring1 3)
(= htoken3 3)
(= htokenring3 3)
(= x5 3)
(= htoken1 3)
(= htoken1ring1 3)
(= x2 3)

unsat

unsat
```

Here the output that I am looking for would be:

```
[1,0,1,0,0].
```

Especially knowing that "sat" is also a substring of "unsat", which causes a problem too.

I tried to use the Pattern and Matcher classes in Java, but I am having ordering problems.

How can I do it in a clean way? I am not looking for the code, but just a proper way to do it.

Comment: It might be better to show your Pattern-Matcher approach - I see no reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: @Deltharis I'm thinking two reasons why this may be tricky: not using `Matcher.find` and not handling multiple lines well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, you could also use a StringReader and read your String line by line.

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(yourString);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("sat")) {
            list.add(1);
        } else if (line.equals("unsat")) {
            list.add(0);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective answer. I was already thinking regexp (using `Matcher.find`) but I don't see why that would be needed here.